# Django - template reloads after ajax response

Tags: python, django, ajax

I'm sort of new with Django and I ran through an issue. I'm sending a post request to django view and return the function back with HttpResponse in order to change my template's div contents to the passed value from my view. The issue is: once ajax responds and changes it's div's value; the page instantly reloads. Do you guys have any idea why?

**Views.py**

```
def index(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    print("request is ajax")
    details = request.POST.get('id')
    return HttpResponse(details)
else:
    return HttpResponse("Failed)
```

**base.html**

```
<button id="checkres">Check result</button>
<form name="testform" id="testform" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="rowfield">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

 $("#testform").submit(function (event){
    $row_num = $('#rowfield').val()
    $("#responseresult").text('checking');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/bot",
        data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(), id: $row_num},
        success: function(data){
            $("#responseresult").text(data);
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: use `JsonResponse` instead of `HttpResponse` see this - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/

Comment: You are calling ajax on submit form. So, your ajax is working fine but because of submitting the form it will reload the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript `submit` event not calling `event.preventDefault()`, that's the reason that after ajax response, the is refreshing. Change your javascript function to:

```
 $("#testform").submit(function (event){
    $row_num = $('#rowfield').val()
    $("#responseresult").text('checking');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/bot",
        data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(), id: $row_num},
        success: function(data){
            $("#responseresult").text(data);
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault(); // prevents the page from refreshing.
});
```

Further read about [**`preventDefault()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been struggling with this for days :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your view

```
def index(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    print("request is ajax")
    details = request.POST.get('id')
    return JsonResponse(details, safe=False)
else:
    return JsonResponse("Failed" safe=False)
```

You need to prevent submit as well.

```
 $("#testform").submit(function (event){
    $row_num = $('#rowfield').val()
    $("#responseresult").text('checking');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/bot",
        data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(), id: $row_num},
        success: function(data){
            $("#responseresult").text(data);
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault(); // prevents the page from refreshing.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response mate, HttpReponse works fine without reloading also if you use  **event.preventDefault();**

Comment: Oh thank you for letting me know as well, I have never tried doing that.